# Why is range()-function slower than multiplying items to get copies inside nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

To copy a nested list in an existing list, it is unfortunately not sufficient to simply multiply it, otherwise references are created and not independent lists in the list, see this example:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3]] * 2
x[0] is x[1]  # will evaluate to True
```

To achieve your goal, you could use the range function in a list comprehension, for example, see this:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(2)]
x[0] is x[1]  # will evaluate to False (wanted behaviour)
```

This is a good way to multiply items in a list without just creating references, and this is also explained multiple times on many different websites.

However, there is a more efficient way to copy the list elements. That code seems a little faster to me (measured by timeit via command line and with different paramater n ∈ {1, 50, 100, 10000} for code below and range(n) in code above):

```
x = [[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * n]
```

But I wonder, why does this code run faster? Are there other disadvantages (more memory consumption or similar)?

```
python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(1)]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.243 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(50)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.79 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(100)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.39 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(10000)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 940 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * 1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.242 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * 50]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.77 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * 100]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.3 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * 10000]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 927 usec per loop


# difference will be greater for larger n

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(1000000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 144 msec per loop

python -m timeit '[[1, 2, 3] for _ in [0] * 1000000]'
10 loops, best of 3: 126 msec per loop
```

Comment: That difference is so exceptionally tiny, it can be considered within the margin of error. Generally as software engineers we only care about factors of 2 or greater.

Comment: I ran the same example for `n == 1`, and the `range` version came out 45 ns faster. There is nothing significant here.

Comment: I wonder, because it's every time faster (on my machine) and greater values will show also greater differences. Adding greater n....

Comment: @FHTMitchell Not really: for small `n` (about 1000) `n*[0]` wins by a large margin (larger than statistical error). For larger `n` (about 1e6), the results that I get are close (larger than 2 sigma) but they are _consistently larger_ (I would expect that `range` would win at least sometimes if the results were statistically close).

Comment: @AGNGazer OK I suppose there's a difference between *statistical* error and *useful* difference.

Comment: @FHTMitchell For n=1000 I get: `n*[0]`: `70.4 µs ± 810 ns` and for `range` I get `79 µs ± 876 ns`. It is a ~13% difference. Is this a useful difference?

Comment: @AGNGazer Not really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct; `range`, even in Python 3 where it produces a compact range object, is more complicated than a list, in the classical tradeoff between computation and storage.

As the list grows too large to fit in cache (the primary question if we're concerned with performance), the range object runs into a different issue: as each number in the range is created, it destroys and creates new `int` objects (the first 256 or so are less costly because they're interned, but their difference can still cost a few cache misses). The list would keep referring to the same one.

There are still more efficient options, though; a bytearray, for instance, would consume far less memory than the list. Probably the best function for the task is hidden away in `itertools`: [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). Like a range object, it doesn't need storage for all the copies, but like the repeated list it doesn't need to create distinct objects. Something like `for _ in repeat(None, x)` would therefore just poke at the same few cache lines (iteration count and reference count for the object).

In the end, the main reason people stick to using `range` is because it's what's prominently presented (both in the idiom for a fixed count loop and among the builtins).

In other Python implementations, it's quite possible for range to be faster than repeat; this would be because the counter itself already holds the value. I'd expect such behaviours from Cython or PyPy.

Comment: Paragraphs might help this answer.